# Which license to use LGPL-3.0, MPL-2.0 or AGPL-3.0 for a library that manages files locally?

Tags: licensing, lgpl, agpl-3.0, mpl

I'm open-sourcing a library that tries to make managing local files easier by enabling full text search, encryption, corruption handling & remote transfer/distribution of files.

What license to use that allows the following?

- Can be used within other open-source projects with different licenses without forcing others to change their license. No viral license
- Can be used within proprietary or commercial closed source software with no restrictions or conditions.
- But has only one condition that any changes, updates and bug-fixes to the library itself (just the library) are published back to the open-source project so that the library maintainers and other developers can benefit from it regardless of where the software is run, locally, remote over a web service or on a Rocket to the Moon.

`MPL-2.0` and `LGPL-3.0` provide the above but they do say that modifications should be published if it's run over a web-service.

`AGPL-3.0` says that modifications should be published if it's run over a web-service but it's a viral license so other open-source projects cannot use my library unless they are `AGPL-3.0` too.

Comment: None of those licenses answers your needs (as you have already stated).  The idea of a "Lesser Affero GPL" has been discussed for years, but I couldn't tell you why it hasn't become a thing yet.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58033/is-there-any-copyleft-gpl-like-license-with-both-the-affero-and-lesser-modific

Comment: One option would be to write your own addendum to the AGPL granting additional rights to distributors, but who knows how enforceable that is:   http://mo.morsi.org/blog/2009/08/13/lesser_affero_gplv3/

Comment: The "Lesser Affero GPL" is exactly what I ended up going with :)